# Running batch file in C# code

Tags: c#

Please help me i have a .bat file in specific location i wanna to execute it and see what happening like if clicked on it manually, the problem is the .bat file running as pop up window for just moment and no process done, My code is like

```
int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;
            string command = @"D:\programs\PreRef\Run.bat";
            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            //processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // *** Redirect the output ***
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();

            // *** Read the streams ***
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            process.Close();
```

So Please help me to solve this problem.Note this `.bat` file run another `.exe` program and the text in the `.bat` file is like `PreRef.exe "D:\programs\PreRef"`

Comment: @duDE That's not necessarily a duplicate.

Comment: Just for the debugging effort, try to change the `/c` parameter in `/K` and comment out the last lines that redirects the process output (leave only the `Process.Start` line). Now you should be able to see the command window and read the output of your batch file

Comment: The same @Steve no process was done

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Process objProcess = new Process();
objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
objProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;   
//file location
objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format(@"D:\programs\PreRef\Run.bat";");
//any argument 
objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("");
try
{
 objProcess.Start();
}
catch
{
 throw new Exception("Error");
}
StreamReader strmReader = objProcess.StandardOutput;
string strTempRow = string.Empty;
while ((strTempRow = strmReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strTempRow);
}
if (!objProcess.HasExited)
{
   objProcess.Kill();
}
```

Comment: No Process i did not see any result @Arshad

Comment: is your batch file working ?

Comment: yup it work great if i execute it manually

Comment: thank you all it works i tried link suggested by @SatpalSingh and it works well thank you all for your help thank you saptalSingh

Comment: @Arshad Why do you catch the exception of `objProcess.Start();` and swallow it which may contain valuable information.